# Jitter coordinates points in ggplot2 within the function geom_sf

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates, shapefile

I have a dataframe called DRCac of coordinate points that looks like this:

| Date | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1/21/22 | POINT (-92.24382 36.25225) |
| 1/22/22 | POINT (-92.24302 36.25116) |
| 1/23/22 | POINT (-92.24382 36.25225) |
| 1/21/22 | POINT (-92.24302 36.25116) |
| 1/22/22 | POINT (-92.24382 36.25225) |

There are close to four hundred points and when plotted with this code they overlap too much on the map. The shapefile they are overlaid on is called System.

```
DRCmap <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = System) +
  geom_sf(data = DRCac, aes(color = Species)) +
  coord_sf(ylim = c(36.246, 36.253), xlim = c(-92.241,-92.245), expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

Is there a way I can jitter the points inside the function geom_sf() or do I have to use a different function. For perspective the direction of east is where the legend is so the jitter would have to be longitudinal.

Answer (score 0):

Hadley seems pretty clear that he does not think this belongs in the `geom_sf()` call. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2332

However, I just had a similar use case, and used `sf::st_jitter()` https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_jitter.html, which worked pretty well.